# I want to pass a list to a function, and expect the function to modify the list

Tags: python

The code for modifying a list passed as argument is as follows. The code does not work. I want to know why it doesn't.

```
def modify_list(some_list):
    for item in some_list:
        item *= 2
        some_list.append(item)
    return some_list

modify_list([2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What did you _expect_ it to do?

Comment: 1) You cannot append to a list while iterating 2) You are appending, not modifying the existing elements

Comment: You must explain the result you expect and the result you are getting, so we can help you.

Comment: @OneCricketeer makes sense, so how can i fix this issue to append elements while iterating.

Comment: Having just tested this, as far as I can tell it will just consume increasing amounts of RAM

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 crashed my PC with 12 GB RAM in just 20 seconds !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append to a list while iterating because then the loop will never end. If you want to append new elements from the existing list, then `extend` the input with those values

```
def modify_list(some_list):
  new_elements = [i*2 for i in some_list]
  some_list.extend(new_elements)
  return some_list
```

Keep in mind, that functions should not have "side-effects"; don't modify the input object reference, which you can do like this

```
def modify_list(some_list):
  copy = some_list[:]
  new_elements = [i*2 for i in some_list]
  copy.extend(new_elements)
  return copy
```

If you want to multiply each element by two, then you don't need a function for that

```
some_list = [2, 4, 6]
some_list = list(map(lambda x: 2*x, some_list))
```

Comment: thanks, that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the function to actually modify the list in place:

```
def modify_list(some_list):
    for i, item in enumerate(some_list):
        some_list[i] *= 2
    

l = [2,4,6]
modify_list(l)
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[4, 8, 12]
```